# DLink DWA‑182 D1 rtl88x2bu not working after upgrading to 19.10

Tags: drivers, upgrade, usb, 19.10

yesterday i've updated my ubuntu version from 19.04 to 19.10.
after that the system is't recognizing anymore the Wifi dongle DLink DWA‑182 D1 rtl88x2bu.

I've the driver from [https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu] and it compiled correctly, but when i plug the usb device i see lot of errors:

```
[ 9930.029322] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
[ 9930.049804] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=2001, idProduct=331c, bcdDevice= 2.10
[ 9930.049809] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 9930.049813] usb 1-9: Product: 802.11ac NIC
[ 9930.049815] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: 123456
[ 9930.051874] RTW:
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(0):
[ 9930.051876] RTW: bLength=7
[ 9930.051877] RTW: bDescriptorType=5
[ 9930.051879] RTW: bEndpointAddress=84
[ 9930.051880] RTW: wMaxPacketSize=512
[ 9930.051881] RTW: bInterval=0
[ 9930.051883] RTW: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_in = 4
[ 9930.051884] RTW:
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(1):
[ 9930.051885] RTW: bLength=7
[ 9930.051886] RTW: bDescriptorType=5
[ 9930.051887] RTW: bEndpointAddress=5
[ 9930.051889] RTW: wMaxPacketSize=512
[ 9930.051890] RTW: bInterval=0
[ 9930.051891] RTW: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 5
[ 9930.051892] RTW:
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(2):
[ 9930.051893] RTW: bLength=7
[ 9930.051894] RTW: bDescriptorType=5
[ 9930.051895] RTW: bEndpointAddress=6
[ 9930.051897] RTW: wMaxPacketSize=512
[ 9930.051898] RTW: bInterval=0
[ 9930.051899] RTW: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 6
[ 9930.051900] RTW:
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(3):
[ 9930.051901] RTW: bLength=7
[ 9930.051902] RTW: bDescriptorType=5
[ 9930.051903] RTW: bEndpointAddress=87
[ 9930.051905] RTW: wMaxPacketSize=64
[ 9930.051906] RTW: bInterval=3
[ 9930.051908] RTW: RT_usb_endpoint_is_int_in = 7, Interval = 3
[ 9930.051909] RTW:
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(4):
[ 9930.051910] RTW: bLength=7
[ 9930.051911] RTW: bDescriptorType=5
[ 9930.051912] RTW: bEndpointAddress=8
[ 9930.051914] RTW: wMaxPacketSize=512
[ 9930.051915] RTW: bInterval=0
[ 9930.051916] RTW: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 8
[ 9930.051918] RTW: nr_endpoint=5, in_num=2, out_num=3

[ 9930.051919] RTW: USB_SPEED_HIGH
[ 9930.051921] RTW: CHIP TYPE: RTL8822B
[ 9930.051983] RTW: [HALMAC]11692M
               HALMAC_MAJOR_VER = 1
               HALMAC_PROTOTYPE_VER = 5
               HALMAC_MINOR_VER = 14
               HALMAC_PATCH_VER = 15
[ 9930.052490] RTW: rtw_hal_config_rftype RF_Type is 2 TotalTxPath is 2
[ 9930.052493] RTW: Chip Version Info: CHIP_8822B_Normal_Chip_UMC_D_CUT_2T2R_RomVer(3)
[ 9930.052498] RTW: config_chip_out_EP OutEpQueueSel(0x07), OutEpNumber(3)
[ 9930.052571] RTW: ERROR [HALMAC][ERR]Dump efuse in suspend
[ 9930.217235] RTW: is_valid_id_status: HALMAC_FEATURE_DUMP_LOGICAL_EFUSE
[ 9930.217274] RTW: HW EFUSE
[ 9930.217278] RTW: 0x000: 29 81 00 3C  09 00 B1 00  94 07 64 00  00 00 A3 00
[ 9930.217290] RTW: 0x010: 27 28 28 28  28 28 24 25  25 25 25 02  00 00 FF FF
[ 9930.217313] RTW: 0x020: FF FF 21 1F  1E 1C 19 18  18 17 1A 1D  21 21 20 20
[ 9930.217323] RTW: 0x030: 02 00 FF FF  00 FF 2C 00  FF FF 2C 2D  2E 2E 2D 2D
[ 9930.217337] RTW: 0x040: 29 2A 2B 2B  2A 22 00 00  FF FF FF FF  1C 1A 19 17
[ 9930.217347] RTW: 0x050: 19 18 17 16  18 1B 1E 1C  1B 1B 01 00  FF FF 00 FF
[ 9930.217356] RTW: 0x060: 2C 00 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217375] RTW: 0x070: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217385] RTW: 0x080: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217397] RTW: 0x090: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217407] RTW: 0x0A0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217416] RTW: 0x0B0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  26 3F 1A 00  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217425] RTW: 0x0C0: FF 09 00 11  00 00 00 00  00 FF 02 FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217491] RTW: 0x0D0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217501] RTW: 0x0E0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217510] RTW: 0x0F0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217519] RTW: 0x100: 01 20 1C 33  C1 67 02 00  AD 24 8F 79  C1 02 03 0E
[ 9930.217529] RTW: 0x110: 03 38 30 32  2E 31 31 61  63 20 4E 49  43 08 03 31
[ 9930.217539] RTW: 0x120: 32 33 34 35  36 FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217548] RTW: 0x130: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217558] RTW: 0x140: 33 0A 1F 01  00 00 21 0F  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217570] RTW: 0x150: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217580] RTW: 0x160: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217589] RTW: 0x170: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217599] RTW: 0x180: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217608] RTW: 0x190: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217618] RTW: 0x1A0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217630] RTW: 0x1B0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217639] RTW: 0x1C0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217649] RTW: 0x1D0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217658] RTW: 0x1E0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217667] RTW: 0x1F0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217677] RTW: 0x200: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217695] RTW: 0x210: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217705] RTW: 0x220: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217714] RTW: 0x230: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217724] RTW: 0x240: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217733] RTW: 0x250: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217745] RTW: 0x260: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217755] RTW: 0x270: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217764] RTW: 0x280: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217774] RTW: 0x290: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217783] RTW: 0x2A0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217793] RTW: 0x2B0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217802] RTW: 0x2C0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217812] RTW: 0x2D0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217824] RTW: 0x2E0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217833] RTW: 0x2F0: FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
[ 9930.217846] RTW: EEPROM ID = 0x8129
[ 9930.217847] RTW: EEPROM Version = 0
[ 9930.217866] RTW: EEPROM Regulatory=0x01
[ 9930.217867] RTW: EEPROM Board Type=0x00
[ 9930.217869] RTW: EEPROM Disable BT-coex, ant_num=1
[ 9930.217872] RTW: hal_com_config_channel_plan chplan:0x26
[ 9930.217874] RTW: EEPROM crystal_cap=0x3f
[ 9930.217875] RTW: EEPROM ThermalMeter=0x1a
[ 9930.217877] RTW: EEPROM Customer ID=0x00
[ 9930.217878] RTW: EEPROM SupportRemoteWakeup=0
[ 9930.217880] RTW: EEPROM PAType_2G is 0x0, ExternalPA_2G = 0
[ 9930.217882] RTW: EEPROM PAType_5G is 0x0, external_pa_5g = 0
[ 9930.217886] RTW: EEPROM LNAType_2G is 0x0, ExternalLNA_2G = 0
[ 9930.217887] RTW: EEPROM LNAType_5G is 0x0, external_lna_5g = 0
[ 9930.217889] RTW: EEPROM TypeGPA = 0x0
[ 9930.217890] RTW: EEPROM TypeAPA = 0x0
[ 9930.217891] RTW: EEPROM TypeGLNA = 0x0
[ 9930.217892] RTW: EEPROM TypeALNA = 0x0
[ 9930.217894] RTW: EEPROM rfe_type=0x2
[ 9930.217898] RTW: ERROR [HALMAC][ERR]Dump efuse in suspend
[ 9930.217970] RTW: is_valid_id_status: HALMAC_FEATURE_DUMP_PHYSICAL_EFUSE
[ 9930.217974] RTW: EEPROM efuse[0x3D7]=0xf3
[ 9930.217975] RTW: EEPROM efuse[0x3D8]=0xf0
[ 9930.217976] RTW: EEPROM USB Switch=1
[ 9930.217978] RTW: EEPROM VID = 0x2001, PID = 0x331C
[ 9930.224165] RTW: [HALMAC][ALWAYS]shall R reg twice!!
[ 9930.224487] RTW: SetHwReg: bMacPwrCtrlOn=1
[ 9930.224524] RTW: rtl8822b_fw_dl fw source from array
[ 9930.261597] RTW: _rtw_hal_set_fw_rsvd_page((null)) Get [ NOR ] RsvdPageNUm  ==>
[ 9930.261600] RTW: LocPsPoll: 4
[ 9930.261602] RTW: LocNullData: 5
[ 9930.261605] RTW: LocQosNull: 6
[ 9930.261607] RTW: LocBTQosNull: 7
[ 9930.261610] RTW: _rtw_hal_set_fw_rsvd_page((null)) Get [ NOR ] RsvdPageNUm <==
[ 9930.265672] RTW: rtl8822b_fw_dl Download Firmware from array success
[ 9930.265676] RTW: NIC FW Version:27 SubVersion:10 FW size:153424
[ 9930.266352] RTW: SetHwReg: bMacPwrCtrlOn=0
[ 9930.269410] RTW: hal_read_mac_hidden_rpt OK! (1, 4ms), fwdl:1, id:0x19
[ 9930.269412] RTW: EEPROM Disable BT-coex by hal_spec
[ 9930.269418] RTW: ERROR [HALMAC][ERR]Dump efuse in suspend
[ 9930.269484] RTW: is_valid_id_status: HALMAC_FEATURE_DUMP_PHYSICAL_EFUSE
[ 9930.269489] RTW: ERROR [HALMAC][ERR]Dump efuse in suspend
[ 9930.269563] RTW: is_valid_id_status: HALMAC_FEATURE_DUMP_PHYSICAL_EFUSE
[ 9930.269566] RTW: ERROR [HALMAC][ERR]Dump efuse in suspend
[ 9930.269643] RTW: is_valid_id_status: HALMAC_FEATURE_DUMP_PHYSICAL_EFUSE
[ 9930.269647] RTW: rtw_hal_read_chip_info in 220 ms
[ 9930.269660] RTW: init_channel_set((null)) ChannelPlan ID:0x26, ch num:32
[ 9930.269775] RTW: init_mlme_default_rate_set: support CCK
[ 9930.269777] RTW: init_mlme_default_rate_set: support OFDM
[ 9930.269990] RTW: NR_RECVBUFF: 8
[ 9930.269991] RTW: MAX_RECVBUF_SZ: 32768
[ 9930.269995] RTW: NR_PREALLOC_RECV_SKB: 8
[ 9930.270177] RTW: rtw_alloc_macid((null)) if1, mac_addr:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff macid:1
[ 9930.270211] RTW: IQK FW offload:enable
[ 9930.270217] RTW: init_phydm_cominfo: fab_ver=1 cut_ver=3
[ 9930.270221] RTW: rtw_regsty_chk_target_tx_power_valid return _FALSE for band:0, path:0, rs:0, t:-1
[ 9930.270242] RTW: phy_ConfigBBWithPgParaFile(): No File PHY_REG_PG.txt, Load from HWImg Array!
[ 9930.270272] RTW: default power by rate loaded
[ 9930.270329] RTW: can't get autopm:
[ 9930.270333] RTW: rtw_macaddr_cfg mac addr:00:ad:24:8f:79:c1
[ 9930.270336] RTW: bDriverStopped:True, bSurpriseRemoved:False, bup:0, hw_init_completed:0
[ 9930.270357] RTW: rtw_cfg80211_preinit_wiphy primary- don't set p2p capability
[ 9930.270361] RTW: rtw_wiphy_alloc(phy2)
[ 9930.270364] RTW: rtw_wdev_alloc(padapter=00000000812e249d)
[ 9930.270368] RTW: rtw_wiphy_register(phy2)
[ 9930.270369] RTW: Register RTW cfg80211 vendor cmd(0x67) interface
[ 9930.270386] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 9930.270483] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 5467 at net/wireless/core.c:868 wiphy_register.cold+0xe4/0x2e5 [cfg80211]
[ 9930.270485] Modules linked in: btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs 88x2bu(OE) cfg80211 aufs overlay xt_state xt_conntrack iptable_filter xt_tcpudp iptable_nat xt_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 bpfilter xfs libcrc32c snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common i915 snd_intel_nhlt drm_kms_helper snd_hda_codec mei_hdcp x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_core intel_powerclamp coretemp drm joydev kvm_intel cdc_acm i2c_algo_bit kvm fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt input_leds snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi mei_me mei snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer irqbypass snd crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul soundcore ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel intel_pch_thermal aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd mac_hid glue_helper intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf mxm_wmi acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4
[ 9930.270551]  hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid ahci r8169 i2c_i801 libahci realtek wmi video
[ 9930.270568] CPU: 3 PID: 5467 Comm: kworker/3:2 Tainted: G        W  OE     5.3.0-46-generic #38-Ubuntu
[ 9930.270570] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./H110M-DVS R2.0, BIOS P8.00 02/26/2018
[ 9930.270578] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
[ 9930.270625] RIP: 0010:wiphy_register.cold+0xe4/0x2e5 [cfg80211]
[ 9930.270629] Code: ff e9 1a 53 fa ff 48 c7 c7 28 c0 e5 c0 e8 9e 74 6b d6 0f 0b b8 ea ff ff ff e9 02 53 fa ff 48 c7 c7 28 c0 e5 c0 e8 86 74 6b d6 <0f> 0b b8 ea ff ff ff e9 ea 52 fa ff 48 c7 c7 28 c0 e5 c0 e8 6e 74
[ 9930.270632] RSP: 0018:ffffb9af43b676a0 EFLAGS: 00010246
[ 9930.270637] RAX: 0000000000000024 RBX: 000000000000000e RCX: 0000000000000006
[ 9930.270640] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000082 RDI: ffff9f9a71f97440
[ 9930.270642] RBP: ffffb9af43b67718 R08: 000000000000073a R09: 0000000000000004
[ 9930.270644] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9f9a38b7d300
[ 9930.270646] R13: ffffb9af40246442 R14: ffffb9af402464e8 R15: ffffffffc10379fc
[ 9930.270649] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9f9a71f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 9930.270651] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 9930.270654] CR2: 00007fbe3f6d1590 CR3: 0000000167a20004 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[ 9930.270656] Call Trace:
[ 9930.270774]  ? rtw_is_dfs_ch+0x31/0x70 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.270911]  ? rtw_regd_apply_flags+0x9f/0xf0 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.271046]  rtw_wiphy_register+0x33/0x40 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.271177]  rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register+0x19/0x40 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.271303]  rtw_os_ndev_register+0x65/0x160 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.271426]  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x71/0xb0 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.271548]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x2a/0x40 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.271668]  rtw_drv_init+0x381/0x430 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.271677]  usb_probe_interface+0xed/0x290
[ 9930.271684]  really_probe+0xfb/0x3a0
[ 9930.271690]  driver_probe_device+0x5f/0xe0
[ 9930.271696]  __device_attach_driver+0x71/0xd0
[ 9930.271701]  ? driver_allows_async_probing+0x50/0x50
[ 9930.271706]  bus_for_each_drv+0x81/0xd0
[ 9930.271712]  __device_attach+0xe1/0x160
[ 9930.271718]  device_initial_probe+0x13/0x20
[ 9930.271722]  bus_probe_device+0x8f/0xa0
[ 9930.271726]  device_add+0x3c7/0x6b0
[ 9930.271731]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
[ 9930.271738]  usb_set_configuration+0x433/0x7d0
[ 9930.271745]  ? kernfs_activate+0x77/0x80
[ 9930.271752]  generic_probe+0x43/0x60
[ 9930.271755]  usb_probe_device+0x31/0x70
[ 9930.271760]  really_probe+0xfb/0x3a0
[ 9930.271766]  driver_probe_device+0x5f/0xe0
[ 9930.271771]  __device_attach_driver+0x71/0xd0
[ 9930.271776]  ? driver_allows_async_probing+0x50/0x50
[ 9930.271781]  bus_for_each_drv+0x81/0xd0
[ 9930.271786]  __device_attach+0xe1/0x160
[ 9930.271792]  device_initial_probe+0x13/0x20
[ 9930.271796]  bus_probe_device+0x8f/0xa0
[ 9930.271800]  device_add+0x3c7/0x6b0
[ 9930.271804]  ? add_device_randomness+0xa0/0x1c0
[ 9930.271809]  usb_new_device.cold+0x12d/0x304
[ 9930.271815]  hub_port_connect+0x500/0x850
[ 9930.271820]  port_event+0x502/0x780
[ 9930.271826]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
[ 9930.271831]  hub_event+0x152/0x390
[ 9930.271835]  ? __schedule+0x2c1/0x6c0
[ 9930.271841]  process_one_work+0x1db/0x380
[ 9930.271845]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x400
[ 9930.271852]  kthread+0x104/0x140
[ 9930.271856]  ? process_one_work+0x380/0x380
[ 9930.271861]  ? kthread_park+0x80/0x80
[ 9930.271867]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[ 9930.271872] ---[ end trace 778d64ca85d0f23a ]---
[ 9930.271875] RTW: rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register rtw_wiphy_register fail for if1
[ 9930.271879] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 9930.272043] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 5467 at /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1694 rtw_os_ndev_register.cold+0x31/0x38 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.272045] Modules linked in: btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs 88x2bu(OE) cfg80211 aufs overlay xt_state xt_conntrack iptable_filter xt_tcpudp iptable_nat xt_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 bpfilter xfs libcrc32c snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common i915 snd_intel_nhlt drm_kms_helper snd_hda_codec mei_hdcp x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_core intel_powerclamp coretemp drm joydev kvm_intel cdc_acm i2c_algo_bit kvm fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt input_leds snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi mei_me mei snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer irqbypass snd crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul soundcore ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel intel_pch_thermal aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd mac_hid glue_helper intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf mxm_wmi acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4
[ 9930.272099]  hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid ahci r8169 i2c_i801 libahci realtek wmi video
[ 9930.272110] CPU: 3 PID: 5467 Comm: kworker/3:2 Tainted: G        W  OE     5.3.0-46-generic #38-Ubuntu
[ 9930.272112] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./H110M-DVS R2.0, BIOS P8.00 02/26/2018
[ 9930.272117] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
[ 9930.272241] RIP: 0010:rtw_os_ndev_register.cold+0x31/0x38 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.272247] Code: 4c 89 e2 48 c7 c6 e0 1d ff c0 48 c7 c7 b7 79 03 c1 83 c1 01 e8 20 a0 53 d6 e9 7c 74 f3 ff 48 c7 c7 70 f8 04 c1 e8 0f a0 53 d6 <0f> 0b e9 7d 74 f3 ff 48 c7 c7 70 f8 04 c1 e8 fc 9f 53 d6 0f 0b 49
[ 9930.272249] RSP: 0018:ffffb9af43b67758 EFLAGS: 00010246
[ 9930.272253] RAX: 0000000000000024 RBX: ffffb9af40243000 RCX: 0000000000000006
[ 9930.272255] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000092 RDI: ffff9f9a71f97440
[ 9930.272257] RBP: ffffb9af43b67778 R08: 000000000000077c R09: 0000000000000004
[ 9930.272259] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9f9a67cd5000
[ 9930.272261] R13: ffffb9af40246442 R14: ffffb9af402464e8 R15: ffffffffc10379fc
[ 9930.272263] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9f9a71f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 9930.272266] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 9930.272268] CR2: 00007fbe3f6d1590 CR3: 0000000167a20004 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[ 9930.272270] Call Trace:
[ 9930.272398]  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x71/0xb0 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.272523]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x2a/0x40 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.272648]  rtw_drv_init+0x381/0x430 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.272654]  usb_probe_interface+0xed/0x290
[ 9930.272663]  really_probe+0xfb/0x3a0
[ 9930.272668]  driver_probe_device+0x5f/0xe0
[ 9930.272674]  __device_attach_driver+0x71/0xd0
[ 9930.272680]  ? driver_allows_async_probing+0x50/0x50
[ 9930.272684]  bus_for_each_drv+0x81/0xd0
[ 9930.272690]  __device_attach+0xe1/0x160
[ 9930.272695]  device_initial_probe+0x13/0x20
[ 9930.272700]  bus_probe_device+0x8f/0xa0
[ 9930.272704]  device_add+0x3c7/0x6b0
[ 9930.272708]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
[ 9930.272714]  usb_set_configuration+0x433/0x7d0
[ 9930.272719]  ? kernfs_activate+0x77/0x80
[ 9930.272727]  generic_probe+0x43/0x60
[ 9930.272730]  usb_probe_device+0x31/0x70
[ 9930.272735]  really_probe+0xfb/0x3a0
[ 9930.272741]  driver_probe_device+0x5f/0xe0
[ 9930.272746]  __device_attach_driver+0x71/0xd0
[ 9930.272751]  ? driver_allows_async_probing+0x50/0x50
[ 9930.272756]  bus_for_each_drv+0x81/0xd0
[ 9930.272761]  __device_attach+0xe1/0x160
[ 9930.272767]  device_initial_probe+0x13/0x20
[ 9930.272772]  bus_probe_device+0x8f/0xa0
[ 9930.272780]  device_add+0x3c7/0x6b0
[ 9930.272784]  ? add_device_randomness+0xa0/0x1c0
[ 9930.272788]  usb_new_device.cold+0x12d/0x304
[ 9930.272792]  hub_port_connect+0x500/0x850
[ 9930.272797]  port_event+0x502/0x780
[ 9930.272802]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
[ 9930.272807]  hub_event+0x152/0x390
[ 9930.272811]  ? __schedule+0x2c1/0x6c0
[ 9930.272816]  process_one_work+0x1db/0x380
[ 9930.272820]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x400
[ 9930.272827]  kthread+0x104/0x140
[ 9930.272830]  ? process_one_work+0x380/0x380
[ 9930.272836]  ? kthread_park+0x80/0x80
[ 9930.272841]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[ 9930.272845] ---[ end trace 778d64ca85d0f23b ]---
[ 9930.289327] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 9930.289371] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 5467 at /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:3161 rtw_os_ndevs_register.cold+0x5b/0x99 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.289371] Modules linked in: btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs 88x2bu(OE) cfg80211 aufs overlay xt_state xt_conntrack iptable_filter xt_tcpudp iptable_nat xt_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 bpfilter xfs libcrc32c snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common i915 snd_intel_nhlt drm_kms_helper snd_hda_codec mei_hdcp x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_core intel_powerclamp coretemp drm joydev kvm_intel cdc_acm i2c_algo_bit kvm fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt input_leds snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi mei_me mei snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer irqbypass snd crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul soundcore ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel intel_pch_thermal aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd mac_hid glue_helper intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf mxm_wmi acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4
[ 9930.289385]  hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid ahci r8169 i2c_i801 libahci realtek wmi video
[ 9930.289388] CPU: 3 PID: 5467 Comm: kworker/3:2 Tainted: G        W  OE     5.3.0-46-generic #38-Ubuntu
[ 9930.289389] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./H110M-DVS R2.0, BIOS P8.00 02/26/2018
[ 9930.289390] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
[ 9930.289422] RIP: 0010:rtw_os_ndevs_register.cold+0x5b/0x99 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.289423] Code: e9 60 7e f3 ff 48 c7 c7 70 f8 04 c1 e8 ed 9d 53 d6 0f 0b 45 31 ed e9 5a 7e f3 ff 48 c7 c7 70 f8 04 c1 89 45 d4 e8 d4 9d 53 d6 <0f> 0b 49 8b bc 24 50 01 00 00 8b 55 d4 48 85 ff 74 09 80 bf 10 46
[ 9930.289423] RSP: 0018:ffffb9af43b67788 EFLAGS: 00010246
[ 9930.289424] RAX: 0000000000000024 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
[ 9930.289425] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff9f9a71f97448 RDI: ffff9f9a71f97448
[ 9930.289425] RBP: ffffb9af43b677b8 R08: ffff9f9a71f97448 R09: 0000000000000004
[ 9930.289426] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9f9a67cd0000
[ 9930.289426] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffffb9af40243000 R15: ffffffffc10379fc
[ 9930.289427] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9f9a71f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 9930.289428] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 9930.289428] CR2: 00007f8628027068 CR3: 000000004460a006 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[ 9930.289429] Call Trace:
[ 9930.289462]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x2a/0x40 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.289494]  rtw_drv_init+0x381/0x430 [88x2bu]
[ 9930.289496]  usb_probe_interface+0xed/0x290
[ 9930.289498]  really_probe+0xfb/0x3a0
[ 9930.289499]  driver_probe_device+0x5f/0xe0
[ 9930.289500]  __device_attach_driver+0x71/0xd0
[ 9930.289502]  ? driver_allows_async_probing+0x50/0x50
[ 9930.289503]  bus_for_each_drv+0x81/0xd0
[ 9930.289504]  __device_attach+0xe1/0x160
[ 9930.289506]  device_initial_probe+0x13/0x20
[ 9930.289507]  bus_probe_device+0x8f/0xa0
[ 9930.289508]  device_add+0x3c7/0x6b0
[ 9930.289509]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
[ 9930.289511]  usb_set_configuration+0x433/0x7d0
[ 9930.289512]  ? kernfs_activate+0x77/0x80
[ 9930.289513]  generic_probe+0x43/0x60
[ 9930.289514]  usb_probe_device+0x31/0x70
[ 9930.289516]  really_probe+0xfb/0x3a0
[ 9930.289517]  driver_probe_device+0x5f/0xe0
[ 9930.289518]  __device_attach_driver+0x71/0xd0
[ 9930.289520]  ? driver_allows_async_probing+0x50/0x50
[ 9930.289521]  bus_for_each_drv+0x81/0xd0
[ 9930.289522]  __device_attach+0xe1/0x160
[ 9930.289523]  device_initial_probe+0x13/0x20
[ 9930.289525]  bus_probe_device+0x8f/0xa0
[ 9930.289525]  device_add+0x3c7/0x6b0
[ 9930.289526]  ? add_device_randomness+0xa0/0x1c0
[ 9930.289528]  usb_new_device.cold+0x12d/0x304
[ 9930.289529]  hub_port_connect+0x500/0x850
[ 9930.289530]  port_event+0x502/0x780
[ 9930.289531]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
[ 9930.289532]  hub_event+0x152/0x390
[ 9930.289533]  ? __schedule+0x2c1/0x6c0
[ 9930.289535]  process_one_work+0x1db/0x380
[ 9930.289536]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x400
[ 9930.289537]  kthread+0x104/0x140
[ 9930.289538]  ? process_one_work+0x380/0x380
[ 9930.289540]  ? kthread_park+0x80/0x80
[ 9930.289541]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[ 9930.289542] ---[ end trace 778d64ca85d0f23c ]---
[ 9930.289543] RTW: rtw_wdev_free(wdev=00000000ebcdbcdc)
[ 9930.289544] RTW: rtw_wiphy_free(phy2)
[ 9930.289548] RTW: rtw_usb_primary_adapter_deinit((null))
[ 9930.289549] RTW: rtw_dev_unload: bup==_FALSE
[ 9930.289551] RTW: +r871xu_dev_remove, hw_init_completed=0
[ 9930.289598] RTW: WARN free_recv_skb_queue not empty, 8
[ 9930.289607] RTW: usb attached..., try to reset usb device
[ 9930.417552] usb 1-9: reset high-speed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
```

BTW the module is loaded successfully

```
lsmod | grep 88
raid6_pq              114688  1 btrfs
jfs                   188416  0
88x2bu               2977792  0
cfg80211              712704  1 88x2bu
```

Am I missing someting?
thanks
Lorenzo